# What ID can be used for children on domestic flights in Australia?

Tags: air-travel, australia, domestic-travel

Children in Australia  usually don’t have a photo ID to travel on domestic flights. What IDs other than a passport can be used for identification?

Comment: You don’t need ID for a domestic flight in Australia.

Answer (score 1):

Photo ID is generally not required for ANY passengers travelling on an Australia Domestic flight.

Airlines may ask for ID when checking baggage, however this is not required for anyone below 18.